# Truth table in programmable logic array in digital electronics

Tags: digital-logic

While studying programmable logic array, I came across this truth table, but couldn't understand the logic how z1 and z0 are filled here?

```
                   x2   x1  x0  z1  z0
                    0   0   0   0   0
                    0   0   1   1   0
                    0   1   0   0   0
                    0   1   1   1   0
                    1   0   0   1   1
                    1   0   1   0   0
                    1   1   0   0   0
                    1   1   1   0   1
```

Is z1 and zo filled randomly? Here is the link of webpage: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Comb/pla.html

Comment: Yes, it looks like the author has filled them "randomly", in order to demonstrate that the PLA is flexible in the ways it can be programmed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Z0 and Z1 as independent problems.  Here is Z0:

```
 x2  x1  x0  z0
  0   0   0   0
  0   0   1   0
  0   1   0   0
  0   1   1   0
  1   0   0   1
  1   0   1   0
  1   1   0   0
  1   1   1   1
```

From the first four lines, it's obvious that

z0 = x2 AND f(x1,x0)

Put another way, whenever X2 is 0, Z0 is also 0.  Put yet another way, when X2 is 0, nothing else matters.  This means we are done with the first four lines.  The equation above yields the correct result regardless of what X1 and X0 are doing there.  This means we now only have to look at the last three columns of the last four lines to determine f(x1,x0):

```
x1  x0  f(x1,x0)
 0   0         1
 0   1         0
 1   0         0
 1   1         1
```

With such a small table, it can be seen immediately from inspection that this is a inverted XOR, sometimes called XNOR.

Putting this all together yields:

z0 = x2 AND (NOT XOR(x1,x0))

Now determine the equation for Z1 similarly.  If you can't see patterns just by looking, as above, use the generalized Karnough map method.